# How do you decrement time for minutes seconds hundredths?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose you wanted to set a timer to whatever time you want will be displayed in the form 00:00:00 minutes, seconds, and hundredths. How would you go about doing so? Please any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the link in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mxpuejvz/2/

```
  function decrement(){
           var time = 600;
           var mins = parseInt((time / 100) / 60);
           var secs = parseInt((time / 100) % 60);
           var hundredths = parseInt(time % 100);
           if(mins < 10) {
              mins = "0" + mins;
           }

           if(secs < 10) {
              secs = "0" + secs;
           }

           if(hundredths < 10) {
              hundredths = "0" + hundredths;
           }

           document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + hundredths;
           if (hundredths === 0){
              if(time ===0){
                 clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Time's Up.";
              }else{
                 time--;
              }
              var countdownTimer = setInterval('decrement()', 10)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is `timeToSeconds`?

Comment: You should setup a jsfiddle

Comment: `time` needs to be a global variable. You're setting it to `600` every time `decrement` is called, so it never decrements.

Comment: If you search SO for javascript countdown timer, you should be able to find hundreds of questions that show how to do it. You don't appear to have done any research before posting.

Comment: I have been searching and all I've been getting is time no decrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues appear to need attention.

1. "time to go" needs to be stored outside the screen update function and decremented or calculated each time the screen is updated.
2. using `parseInt` to convert numbers to integer numbers is regarded as a hack by some. `Math.floor()` or integer calculation can be alternatives.
3. Timer call backs are not guaranteed to made exactly on time: counting the number of call backs for a 10msec time does not give the number of 1/100ths of elapsed time.

*The following code is an **example** of how it could work, minus any pause button action.*

```
var countdownTimer;
var endTime;
var counter = 0;  // ** see reply item 3. **

function startCountDown( csecs)   // hundredths of a second
{   endTime = Date.now() + 10*csecs; // endTime in millisecs
    decrement();
    countdownTimer = setInterval(decrement, 10);
    counter = 0; // testing
}

function decrement()
{   var now, time, mins, secs, csecs, timeStr;

    ++ counter; // testing

    now = Date.now();
    if( now >= endTime)
    {   time = 0;
        timeStr = "Times up! counter = " + counter;
        clearInterval( countdownTimer);
    }
    else
    {   time = Math.floor( (endTime - now)/10); // unit = 1/100 sec
        csecs = time%100;
        time = (time-csecs)/100; // unit = 1 sec
        secs = time % 60;
        mins = (time-secs)/60;   // unit = 60 secs
        timeStr =  
          ( (mins < 10)  ? "0" + mins : mins) + ":" +
          ( (secs < 10)  ? "0" + secs : secs) + ":" +
          ( (csecs < 10) ? "0" + csecs : csecs);
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=timeStr;
}
```

---

The argument to `startCountDown` gives the number of 1/100ths of second for the count down. If the counter result is the same as the argument,try swapping browser tabs and back again during the countdown.

HTML to test:

```
<button type="button" onclick="startCountDown(600)">start</button>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: could you run this through JSFiddle?

Comment: have updated the reply with HTML to run. Issue 3 is the important one - on a notebook or swapping tabs in Firefox produces rather large differences between interval timer calls and elapsed time.

Comment: Honestly I've been going at this for days... And have gotten no where.